# How do I encrypt the Telerik Rad Editor viewstate?

Tags: asp.net, encryption, telerik, viewstate

The viewstate or application's pages are already encrypted but looking at the Burp output of the response from a POST to the Telerik.UI.DialogHandler (ImageMananger) it seems the Telerik view state in the response appears not to be. See attached image.

[Burp output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TX4i4.png)

We've generated and specified the DialogParametersEncryptionKey, ConfigurationEncryptionKey, and ConfigurationHashKey keys in the site level web.config as described in article https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/editor/functionality/dialogs/security. This didn't change the viewstate.

The machine key in IIS is set for auto-generation.

I'm only assuming the Telerik viewstate can be encrypted because what I've read seems to imply that, but I haven't found a clear example so I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please change the TargetFramework of the application to 4.5 or above and test again:

```
>  <compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.8" />
>     <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.8" />
>     <pages viewStateEncryptionMode="Always" enableViewStateMac="true">
>         <controls>
>             <add tagPrefix="telerik" namespace="Telerik.Web.UI" assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" />
>         </controls>
>     </pages>
>     <httpHandlers>
```

It is also a must to set viewStateEncryptionMode="Always" enableViewStateMac="true" in the page directive or the web.config.

Check out this product forum thread for more information: https://www.telerik.com/forums/can-the-rad-editor-viewstate-be-encrypted.